# Grant SQL User to view all SQL Server users

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to grant a SQL Server user permissions to query all SQL Server users, without adding the user to the **sysadmin group** from security?

If yes, could you please guide me?

Thank you + BR

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: You might want to [start here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#_examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can grant him **VIEW ANY DEFINITION** privilege. It still grants more than required but it's not **sysadmin** role.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
USE master;  
GRANT SELECT ON sys.database_principals TO YourUser;  
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE to YourUser;  
GO
```